# About Cauchy's Functional Equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hamel-basis

It's known that the solutions to the Cauchy's Functional Equation:

$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$

are of the form $f(x) = cx$, where $c$ is a constant. I've read that this situation takes place when the function $f(x)$ is continuous. But I would like to know if all the solutions to the Cauchy's Functional Equation can be described by using the theorem on the existence of Hamel bases.

Comment: You might want to read up on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). The first section explains this phenomenon.

Comment: Yes.  From Cauchy's functional equation we can prove $f(ax) = af(x)$ for all rational $a$, and therefore $f$ is $\mathbb Q$-linear.  Any $\mathbb Q$-linear map is determined by its values on a Hamel basis.